Logic App Standard Unit Testing Framework - Unable to Mock HTTP Request to external apis
We are using the Logic App Standard Unit Testing Framework (https://github.com/LogicAppUnit/TestingFramework) and we have run into an issue where we are unable to mock an HTTP request to an external API. No matter how we build the Mock, we receive live data back from the system.
In larger tests we have been able to mock request to local function app actions, but are unable to mock requests to an external API using the HTTP action.
We have confirmed that all the parameters we use to attempt a match are valid and identical to the action. We've tried several different ways to match.
Test.cs: https://github.com/user-attachments/files/17822347/HttpTriggerTests2.cs.txt
Parameters.json: https://github.com/user-attachments/files/17822349/parameters.json
testConfiguration.json: https://github.com/user-attachments/files/17822350/testConfiguration.json
Tests.csproj:  https://github.com/user-attachments/files/17822351/Tests.csproj.txt
workflow.json: https://github.com/user-attachments/files/17822352/workflow.json
Sample Data:

{
"users": [
{
"id": 1001101,
"first_name": "Jack",
"last_name": "Wilson",
"email": "jwilson@email.com",
"telephone": "",
"timezone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
"weekly_capacity": 144000,
"has_access_to_all_future_projects": false,
"is_contractor": true,
"is_active": true,
"calendar_integration_enabled": false,
"calendar_integration_source": null,
"created_at": "2024-11-05T21:18:55Z",
"updated_at": "2024-11-05T21:25:58Z",
"can_create_projects": false,
"default_hourly_rate": 150,
"cost_rate": null,
"roles": [
"Integration Developer"
],
"access_roles": [
"member"
],
"permissions_claims": [
"expenses:read:own",
"expenses:write:own",
"timers:read:own",
"timers:write:own"
],
"avatar_url": "https://f8df58sdf58sdf5.mocked.net/v2/default-avatars/d8D8.png"
},
{
"id": 1001102,
"first_name": "Sasha",
"last_name": "Miller",
"email": "s.miller@email.com",
"telephone": "",
"timezone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
"weekly_capacity": 144000,
"has_access_to_all_future_projects": false,
"is_contractor": true,
"is_active": true,
"calendar_integration_enabled": false,
"calendar_integration_source": null,
"created_at": "2024-04-08T19:52:51Z",
"updated_at": "2024-05-30T07:48:13Z",
"can_create_projects": false,
"default_hourly_rate": 0,
"cost_rate": 0,
"roles": [
"Project Manager"
],
"access_roles": [
"member"
],
"permissions_claims": [
"expenses:read:own",
"expenses:write:own",
"timers:read:own",
"timers:write:own"
],
"avatar_url": "https://E8A58Df85fsdf8d.mocked.net/v2/default-avatars/8D58.png"
},
{
"id": 1001103,
"first_name": "Luke",
"last_name": "Walker",
"email": "lukewalker@email.com",
"telephone": "",
"timezone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
"weekly_capacity": 144000,
"has_access_to_all_future_projects": false,
"is_contractor": true,
"is_active": true,
"calendar_integration_enabled": false,
"calendar_integration_source": null,
"created_at": "2024-04-08T19:52:51Z",
"updated_at": "2024-05-30T07:48:13Z",
"can_create_projects": false,
"default_hourly_rate": 0,
"cost_rate": 0,
"roles": [
"Integration Contractor"
],
"access_roles": [
"member"
],
"permissions_claims": [
"expenses:read:own",
"expenses:write:own",
"timers:read:own",
"timers:write:own"
],
"avatar_url": "https://8E5e357s2d12g45.mocked.net/v2/default-avatars/f85e.png"
}
],
"per_page": 2000,
"total_pages": 1,
"total_entries": 12,
"next_page": null,
"previous_page": null,
"page": 1,
"links": {
"first": "https://api.mockedharvestapp.com/v2/users?is_active=true&page=1&per_page=2000&ref=first",
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"last": "https://api.mockedharvestapp.com/v2/users?is_active=true&page=1&per_page=2000&ref=last"
} }


can you share the error message

There is no error message. Everything runs successfully. It just doesn't mock the endpoint at all.

Can you share the data you would like to mock

Updated with the data to mock as well as some links to the code files that i thought were already linked.
